# What happens if a linux kernel argument is passed twice with different values?

Tags: linux, centos, fedora, kernel

As the question states, what if I pass

```
kernel /vmlinuz audit=1 audit=0
```

Will auditing enabled or disabled? Or will the kernel just freak out? Or is it undefined and will depend on the build of the kernel/argument being passed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, looking at the Vanilla code in [linux/kernel/params.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2.6/kernel/params.c#L93) and the `parse_one` function (for v3.2.6) I would assume that `audit=0` would be the version used by the kernel as its the last one in the list.

> ```
> static int parse_one(char *param,
>                    char *val,
>                    const struct kernel_param *params,
>                    unsigned num_params,
>                    int (*handle_unknown)(char *param, char *val))   {
>      unsigned int i;
>      int err;
>
>      /* Find parameter */
>      for (i = 0; i < num_params; i++) {
>              if (parameq(param, params[i].name)) {
>                      /* No one handled NULL, so do it here. */
>                      if (!val && params[i].ops->set != param_set_bool)
>                              return -EINVAL;
>                      DEBUGP("They are equal!  Calling %p\n",
>                             params[i].ops->set);
>                      mutex_lock(&param_lock);
>                      err = params[i].ops->set(val, &params[i]);
>                      mutex_unlock(&param_lock);
>                      return err;
>              }
>      }
>
>      if (handle_unknown) {
>              DEBUGP("Unknown argument: calling %p\n", handle_unknown);
>              return handle_unknown(param, val);
>      }
>
>      DEBUGP("Unknown argument `%s'\n", param);
>      return -ENOENT;  }
> ```

I am not near a GNU/Linux machine to verify this right now, and it would also depend on patches done by the distributor of your kernel.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll look in RHELs src for this file and verify it is indeed the same.